# variable editing in ruby (as in zsh's vared)

Tags: ruby

I am converting a zsh shell app to ruby. I am used to using zsh's `vared` for letting user edit value of variable. Is there any equivalent in ruby?

This is a command-line app. I currently am using ruby's `gets` but this does not allow editing of a previous value. I once used `highline`, but IIRC, it allows using up arrow to get history, which is quite close, but not the same thing.

edit: I meant `readline` when i said `highline`. I use both actually.

Comment: You're right, `gets` does not allow editing any values. It's not its job. It just reads strings. Editing is up to you. Post some code you've written

Comment: @sergio: The zsh app is at https://github.com/rkumar/zfm , the portion I have rewritten in ruby is at: https://github.com/rkumar/lyra

I have actually implemented editing of values using getch years back but that was inside ncurses (rbcurse gem), and I want to stay outside ncurses for this program, and i don't want to do all the trapping of keys etc all over again. I guess I could copy over the code and redo it but hoping there's a solution i can use that I may have missed out.